# Cannot call method 'update' of undefined Cgridcview

Tags: php, yii

`$.fn.yiiGridView.update('sopodetail-grid'+itemcd);`
this function it's not running.

It says `Cannot call method 'update' of undefined` in console.

I have problem when inserting data via ajax `gridview` not refreshing.

I render multiple grid view with foreach looping, and make each of them unique id with concatenating `item_cd`.

```
 function validateDetailForm()
    {
        var jForm   = $('#sopodetail-form');                                                    
        var data    = jForm.serialize();
        var itemcd  = $('#cmbitemcd').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : jForm.attr('action'),
            data: data,
            dataType:'html',
            success:function(data) 
            {

                $(".info").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 3000).fadeOut("slow");
                $.fn.yiiGridView.update('sopodetail-grid'+itemcd);
            },
            error: function(data) { // if error occured
                alert('Error occured.please try again');
                $('#detail-content').html(data);
            },
        });
    }
```

this how i can render multiple gridview i concating the id...

```
foreach($modelSoDet as $modelSoDetObj):
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
            'data'=>$modelSoDetObj,
            'attributes'=>array(
                'item_cd',
                'item.item_name',
                'item.item_desc',
                'qty',
                'qty_purchased'
            )
    ));

    $modelSoPoDetail = new Sopodetail();
    $modelSoPoDetail->unsetAttributes();
    $modelSoPoDetail->so_cd   = $modelSoDetObj->so_cd;
    $modelSoPoDetail->item_cd = $modelSoDetObj->item_cd;
    $gridid           = 'sopodetail-grid'.$modelSoPoDetail->item_cd; 

    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'dataProvider'=>$modelSoPoDetail->search(),
            'summaryText' => '',
            'id'=>$gridid,
            'columns'=>array(
                'type',
                'po_cd',
                'qty'
            )
    ));
            endforeach;
```

Comment: I hope i can get the answer TT

Comment: "I have a problem" is not a question...

Answer (score 0):

You should simply try with the right syntax :

```
$('sopodetail-grid'+itemcd).yiiGridView('update');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.param.querystring` is called from the `yiiGridView.update` and is located in the `jquery.ba-bbq.js`.

check your HTML source if you have the `jquery.ba-bbq.js` included...

If the `jquery.ba-bbq.js` is included then you may be recreating the jQuery object after `jquery.ba-bbq.js`. E.g. jQuery is loaded more than once....

Source: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/9387-cgridview-update/